What is the reason for near-zero step size in ODE Integration using solve_ivp
I am using scipy.integrate.solve_ivp with the BDF method to solve a complex ODE system. However, the time step is always near zero during the integration, which may lead to an endless ODE integration.
I would like to ask for explanations of reasons for this problem, and feasible solutions to get the final integration results (rapidly).

Edited:
Please refer to the code uploaded here.
PS: regrettably the PDE/ODE system is inherently complex, which makes the code intricate as well.
Thank you so much for your help :)

Welcome to SO, please read [mcve] and [ask], then update your post accordingly.

This question is very general. Please provide a specific example. Without an example we don't know if the step size is small because you have a very stiff system or because of some other reason.

Many thanks. I have updated the post to provide more details to specify this problem.

General reason: the space derivatives on the right side are unbounded as endomorphisms. This means that the right side in the discretized ODE system has very large (local) Lipschitz constants, the larger the finer the discretization is. The maximal admissible step size (for explicit methods) in the time integration is inverse proportional to this Lipschitz constant. Non-linear right sides are usually worse than linear ones with the same scale of coefficients. This is one of the reasons that operator splitting methods were invented. Implicit methods are often too expensive.

@LutzLehmann Thank you for the comment. I'll go a bit deep into theories and look for potential solutions.
